# Display correct format of Data in php

Tags: sql, database, date, format

Below is my code of display of value in the database. I want the output be like:
      21 July 2019 and not like 2019-07-21  . Any ideas and help?

```
 <?php $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
  $dbname = "software";


  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }



   SELECT * From (select * from training_calendar ORDER BY        training_calendar_id DESC LIMIT 2) AS name ORDER BY training_calendar_id   LIMIT 1
 $sql = "SELECT * From (select * from training_calendar ORDER BY   training_calendar_id DESC LIMIT 2) AS name ORDER BY training_calendar_id  LIMIT 1";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 //if ($result->num_rows > 0) {



    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo " ". $row["date_of_training"]. "<br> ";


  }

  //} else {
     //  echo "0 results";
  //} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format date, below code will do your job-

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "software";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * From (select * from training_calendar ORDER BY   training_calendar_id DESC LIMIT 2) AS name ORDER BY training_calendar_id  LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo " " . date("j F Y", strtotime($row["date_of_training"])) . "<br> ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use DATE_FORMAT function of Mysql while retrieving the data or Use date function of PHP to format the date.

> echo date("j F Y",strtotime("2019-07-21"));